# Why prime avoidance lemma allows only at most 2 non-prime ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

> Why prime avoidance lemma allows only at most 2 non-prime ideals?

The following is the last part of the proof taken from wikipedia:

For the case $n > 2$, choose $z_i \in E \cap (I_i - \cup_{j \ne i} I_j), \, \, 1 \le i \le n$ and then put $z = z_1 \cdots z_{n-1} + z_n.$ Then z is in E but not in any of $I_i$'s. Indeed, if z is in $I_i$ for some $i \le n - 1$, then $z_n$ is in $I_i$, a contradiction. If z is in $I_n$, then $z_1 \dots z_{n-1}$ is in $I_n$ and, since $I_n$ is a prime ideal, $z_i$ is in $I_n$, a contradiction. (Note, after the initial reduction, we only need the fact that $I_n$ is a prime ideal.)

From what I see, as long as one of them is prime, say $I_n$. What am I misunderstanding here? The part on z in $I_i$ does not need $I_i$ to be prime, does it? I think it just need $I_i$ to be ideal.

Comment: If your question is not self-contained (notation etc), you should link to references.

Comment: It doesn't allow *at most 2 prime ideals*, it allows **at most two nonprime ideals**. It is slightly curious this is the case, but I imagine there is at least an unsatisfying explanation along the lines of "because this step in the proof just works."

Comment: @rschwieb sorry i meant at most 2 non-prime ideals. I can't figure out the reason from the proof

Comment: Maybe because for three non-prime ideals the lemma fails?

Comment: @user26857 the question i am asking now is why it fails

Comment: Sorry to necropost, but I just had this question as well, and just realized the answer. Yes after the initial reduction we only need one to be prime, but to guarantee that at least one prime remains (if n>2) we need there to be at most two nonprime ideals, so that no matter how many prime ideals are removed in the initial reduction, there will be at least one prime left if there are at least three ideals left.